# How to add object to state from props in ReactJS using firestoreConnect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using firebase in my project. On a component, I would like to show information about the device stored in firestore. I transfer the information to props using react-redux-firebase. But I can't use the props directly or by throwing it into the state.

I tried to use both methods.

```
class Budget extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     dev: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({
     dev: this.props.devices
   })
  }

  render() {
    const {devices, profile, classes, className, ...rest } = this.props;

    const rootClassName = classNames(classes.root, className);

    console.log(this.state)

    return (
      <Paper
        {...rest}
        className={rootClassName}
      >
        <div className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.details}>
            <Typography
              className={classes.title}
              variant="body2"
            >
              Device
            </Typography>

            <Typography
              className={classes.value}
              variant="h3"
            >
              Device condition
            </Typography>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.iconWrapper}>
            <MoneyIcon className={classes.icon} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.footer}>
          <Typography
            className={classes.deviceError}
            variant="body2"
          >
            <Error />
            Error
          </Typography>
          <Typography
            className={classes.deviceOk}
            variant="body2"
          >
            <Done />
            Running
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

Budget.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps =(state) => {
  return {
    authError: state.auth.authError,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    profile: state.firebase.profile,
    devices: state.firestore.ordered.devices
  }
}

export default compose(withStyles(styles),
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect((props)=>[
    {
      collection: 'devices',
      where: [
        ['managerId', '==', props.auth.uid],
      ]
    },
  ]))(Budget);
```

When I run the above code, the 'dev' in the state appears to be undefined. 
If I use devices props in return, i have this error message: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Can't read property 'name' of undefined".
Name is key of a device object.